# Creating azure VM from image with Node SDK

Tags: node.js, azure, virtual-machine

I'm trying to use the azure sdk ([azure-sdk-for-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/computeManagement/README.md)) to create a virtual machine based on an image i've already saved. I've also already created the service.

Here is what I've got:

```
// Create a virtual machine in the cloud service.
computeManagementClient.virtualMachines.createDeployment('prerender-pro', {
  name: "prerender-pro",
  deploymentSlot: "Production",
  label: "for heavy duty caching",
  roles: [{
    roleName: "prerender-pro",
    roleType: "PersistentVMRole",
    label: "for heavy duty caching",
    oSVirtualHardDisk: {
      sourceImageName: "prerender-os-2014-07-16",
      mediaLink: "https://XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/prerender-os-2014-07-16.vhd"
    },
    dataVirtualHardDisks: [],
    configurationSets: [{
      configurationSetType: "LinuxProvisioningConfiguration",
      adminUserName: "Blah",
      adminPassword: "Blahblah2014!",
      computerName: 'prerender-pro',
      enableAutomaticUpdates: true,
      resetPasswordOnFirstLogon: false,
      storedCertificateSettings: [],
      inputEndpoints: []
    }, {
      configurationSetType: "NetworkConfiguration",
      subnetNames: [],
      storedCertificateSettings: [],
      inputEndpoints: [{
        localPort: 3389,
        protocol: "tcp",
        name: "RemoteDesktop"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.info(result);
  }
});
```

And the error I'm getting is this. I follow the example in the github readme almost exactly. Not sure why this is an issue.

```
{ [Error: A computer name must be specified.]
  code: 'BadRequest',
  statusCode: 400,
  requestId: '9206ea1e591eb4dd8ea21a9196da5d74' }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error message is inaccurate.  When deploying a Linux instance, only the "HostName" is required when defining the Configuration Set. "ComputerName" applies only to Windows instances.  Here's an example of C# code:

```
ConfigurationSet configSet = new ConfigurationSet
        {
            HostName = "VMTest",
            UserName="xxxxx",
            UserPassword="xxxx",
            ConfigurationSetType = ConfigurationSetTypes.LinuxProvisioningConfiguration
         }
```

Comment: This should not be an answer. It's not addressing the question. Please use the comments section for such interventions :)

Comment: @morgs32: I'm facing the same issue right now, have you figured out what was the problem?

Comment: @xcoder37 it was a legitimate issue. I'm not sure it was ever fixed. and i ended up living without it. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/1262