# azure create vm fail (add role)

Tags: java, azure, sdk, role

**Create VM request infomation**

URI:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/services/hostedservices/hostzuntmhqzio/deployments/vmtestdeploy1muv/roles
```

Request Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<PersistentVMRole
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RoleName>jdkimtestazs</RoleName>
    <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>
    <ConfigurationSets>
        <ConfigurationSet i:type="LinuxProvisioningConfigurationSet">
        <ConfigurationSetType>LinuxProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
            <ComputerName>jdkimtestazs</ComputerName>
            <AdminPassword>inslab1234!</AdminPassword>
            <EnableAutomaticUpdates>false</EnableAutomaticUpdates>
            <StoredCertificateSettings/>
            <AdminUsername>inslab</AdminUsername>
            <UserName>inslab</UserName>
            <UserPassword>inslab1234!</UserPassword>
            <DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>false</DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>
        </ConfigurationSet>
        <ConfigurationSet>
            <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>
            <InputEndpoints>
                <InputEndpoint>
                    <LocalPort>22</LocalPort>
                    <Name>SSH</Name>
                    <Port>22</Port>
                    <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>
                    <EnableDirectServerReturn>false</EnableDirectServerReturn>
                </InputEndpoint>
                <InputEndpoint>
                    <LocalPort>8080</LocalPort>
                    <Name>tomcat</Name>
                    <Port>8080</Port>
                    <Protocol>tcp</Protocol>
                    <EnableDirectServerReturn>false</EnableDirectServerReturn>
                </InputEndpoint>
            </InputEndpoints>
            <ComputerName>jdkimtestazs</ComputerName>
            <StoredCertificateSettings/>
        </ConfigurationSet>
    </ConfigurationSets>
    <OSVirtualHardDisk>
        <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
        <DiskName>vmtestoshdname74</DiskName>
        <MediaLink>http://storagevmopzzwval.blob.core.windows.net/vhd-store/vmtest74.vhd</MediaLink>
        <SourceImageName>0b11de9248dd4d87b18621318e037d37__RightImage-Ubuntu-14.04-x64-v14.1</SourceImageName>
        <OS>Linux</OS>
    </OSVirtualHardDisk>
    <RoleSize>Medium</RoleSize>
    <ProvisionGuestAgent>true</ProvisionGuestAgent>
</PersistentVMRole>
```

Exception Log:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: BadRequest: A computer name must be specified.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.create(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:5418)
    at seabream.VirtualMachineOperator.createVirtualMachines(VirtualMachineOperator.java:414)
    at seabream.RunTest.main(RunTest.java:15)
Caused by: com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: BadRequest: A computer name must be specified.
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException.createFromXml(ServiceException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.beginCreating(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:1933)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl$3.call(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:1050)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl$3.call(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:1)
```

I specify the computer name , why the error ...

Comment: Can you format this as code so it is easier to read, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773837/creating-azure-vm-from-image-with-node-sdk describes a difference between specifying `HostName` and `ComputerName` - does that help?