# Azure creating virtual machine using node js Sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, virtual-machine

i am unable to find any documentation/examples  to create/ manage a azure virtual machine using the azure node js sdk in java-script,they seem to have so many versions and documentation is very poor. appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is poor to use the Azure Management API with node js, the full documentation is disponible on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node).

To create ASM virtual machines, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/computeManagement) is a complete example to create an azure virtual machine using node js, besides you can use this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773837/creating-azure-vm-from-image-with-node-sdk?rq=1) too.

To create ARM virtual machines with node js, a solution would be to create an ARM template of the virtual machine and deploy it as a "generic resource", here is the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/resourceManagement).

Answer (score 0):

As supplementary, there is a sample for creating Azure VM on ARM mode, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/ARM/compute/vm-sample.js.

Besides using Azure SDK for Node, you also can use the Azure REST APIs for creating VM. Azure SDK for Node just wrapped these REST APIs. The documents for using REST APIs explain how to do it in detail, please see below.

1. For using ARM mode, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163647.aspx.
2. For using ASM mode, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157206.aspx.